# Performance drop after change tracking & isolation snapshot

Tags: sql-server, performance, snapshot-isolation, change-tracking

Several days ago, I enabled change tracking on a db and some of its tables.
A few days ago, I also `SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON`.

(Probably important note: I never `SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON`, and the only procedures/queries that actually used transaction isolation where a few manual runs by myself, which I saw them run to completion within a logical time frame).

A few days after that, we got reports of decreased performance. I am aware that both of these things impact performance in a minor(?) way, but i am not sure how to measure this yet. So, for the sake of being on the safe side, I `SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF`, and also disabled change tracking on every table first and on the whole db in the end.

The performance problems remain. So my questions are:

- Can change tracking and/or ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION cause performance drop in a server/database even AFTER they are disabled? If so, how, and how can I check and fix the problem?

I run a few queries from [this site](https://www.sqlshack.com/monitor-sql-server-tempdb-database/) to check the state of tempdb but did not find any interestingly large table.

Comment: When you say "performance problem", you'll need to provide more information. What isn't performing well? Do you have any stats collected to prove the slowdown?

Comment: It is highly unfortunate that I really don't have more info. Instictively, I highly doubt that MS would allow a performance drop caused by a *disabled* option, so I bet this "performance drop" (same queries take longer times) is caused by something else 99%. I could pose specific questions if you recommend some; although the nature of the question remains intact. If the answer is a simple "no", then I'm fine.

Comment: Do you have Query Store enabled? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: when you see perf issues - what are the waits associated ?